# Get data from a model based on a list from another model object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models as follow :

```
class Books(models.Model):
    poster = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    bookid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    year = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class UserRating(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    bookid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

In the `views.py` I get all the current logged in user rates and put it in `bookid` list :

```
def rated(request):

    rate = UserRating.objects.filter(userid=request.user.id)[:5]
    bookid =  []

    for i in rates:
        bookid.append(i.bookid)
```

What I want to do is getting every book poster by its bookid.diplaying all books that the user rated with its poster and the rate.

How can I do that?

Comment: I do not really get what the `poster` is doing here?

Comment: You really should be using `models.ForeignKey()`s (to `User` and `Books` [sic]) instead of poorly emulating them with CharFields.

Comment: that is the image url of book cover

Comment: Furthermore like AKX says, it is no good practice to write `ids`, instead of using `ForeignKey`s. By using such keys, you can let the ORM make joins. Furthermore a reasonable database system will enforce that the `id`s match.

Comment: Someone else had written this code and I need to fix it. `userid` in the `UserRating` model should use ForeignKey, thats true. What about the others?

Comment: @Ali: using *singular* model names. That is basically it. `ForeignKey`s are not only a more direct mapping to what it is, it also offers a lot of convenience to obtain, query, modify `Book`s and `UserRating`s.

Answer (score 1):

The modeling is rather strange: you ue `CharField`s as a way to link objects together. But that is not a good practice. Django has a tool to link model objects together: `ForeignKey`s:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    poster = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    year = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Furthermore a `rating` is probably more *numerical*, so an `IntegerField`, or a `DecimalField`. A model name is typically *singular* (so `Book` instead of `Books`). Finally usually one does not assign an `id` to a model instance: Django does this automatically. If the `bookid` is more something like an ISBN, then you can create a field `isbn = ...` in a `Book`.

With these changes, one can exploit the `ForeignKey` relations, and thus use the ORM to make JOINs. For example we can obtain all the `Book`s a user has rated (together with the rating) with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Book.objects.filter(
    userrating__user=request.user
).annotate(
    rating=F('userrating__rating')
)
```

Here the queryset will contain all the books the `request.user` has rated. Furtermore every `Book` of *this* querset will have an attribute `.rating` that contains the rating of the user for that book.

I would also advice to define a `ManyToManyField` for the `Book` model to `User` (the `raters`), and let it thus pass through `UserRating`.

Comment: Thanks Willem. Yes actually the `bookid` is something unique like ISBN or serial number. I need to access the poster of each book that user have rated. How to write that filter?

Comment: @Ali: you can simply iterate over the books of the queryset, and thus access the `book.poster`.